# How to use RegEx to collect info for multiple landing page URLs?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, looker-studio, re2

I've got 120 URLs that I need to pull Google Analytics data, for use in Google Data Studio. My URLs consist of:

```
test.com/9846
test.com/3726
test.com/5789
test.com/2876
```

I've tried using the below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
LANDING PAGE - CONTAINS - (9846|3726|5789|2876)
```

Comment: You may try `https?://.*/(?:9846|3726|5789|2876)`

Answer (score 0):

Not `Contains`, you should choose `RegExp Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have provided a few examples out of the mentioned 120 variables, it all depends on the actual pattern of these URLs. Nevertheless, you should build a regular expression instead of the Contains operator.

Assuming you use 4 digits, you could use something like this:

Landing page - matches regex - `^\/(\d){4}`

This requires to match start of the string (as default Analytics setup does not include domain), a / sign, and exactly 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `RegExp Contains`.
To use your exact example, the filter condition should be:

```
LANDING PAGE - RegExp Contains - (9846|3726|5789|2876)
```

From the [doc on filters](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7327641?hl=en&ref_topic=7327560) on `RegExp Contains`:

> The dimension value contains the regular expression.
>   **Example**
>
> `(?i)C[a-z]*` matches `chrome`, `Chrome`, `Chromebook` and `Google Chrome`
>
> `Regexp Contains` looks for the regular expression anywhere in the data.
>
> The `(?i)` flag makes the regular expression case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

To [Filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066) the URLs, the following two formulas do the trick:

> **1. Ends with `9846|3726|5789|2876`**
>
> ```
> Include LANDING PAGE RegExp_Match (9846|3726|5789|2876)$
> ```
>
> **2. `test.com` URLs that end with `9846|3726|5789|2876`**
>
> ```
> Include LANDING PAGE RegExp_Match ^test\.com/(9846|3726|5789|2876)$
> ```

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b35f487a-a56e-4e63-9ca4-ba19f380ef11) (Google Sheets Embedded) to demonstrate.

[image: 2]]